# Macro to reverse tracked changes in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

A lot of my work involves negotiating tech contracts, and the industry convention is that the two parties send each other marked-up MS Word documents showing the changes they'd like. This often happens multiple times before it is agreed.

Often a paragraph will come back with many insertions/deletions, which we don't want to accept. Again, the convention is that even rejecting these changes needs to be marked up, so that each of their individual insertions (blue text) must now be marked as deletions (red strikeout) and vice versa.

Does anyone know of a macro that can do this? Or know how to write one? I've spent hours searching online and trying to teach myself to code one, but I'm getting nowhere!

I think the easiest way would be to alter the *Revision.Type* property of each *Revision* in the selection from *wdRevisionDelete* to *wdRevisionInsert* (or vice versa), but this seems to be a read-only property.

I've tried assigning deleted text to a string, accepting the change, and then inserting it, but cannot get it to go in the right place. I also can't find how to delete the inserted text, so can't get anywhere with the other side of the equation.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally, I'd be able to select some text, run the macro, and have each revision 'flipped'. It sounds so simple, but I cannot find a way. It would honestly save me hours per month, so I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could help.

Thanks in advance!
James

Comment: Do you have any code all all to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't answer a question with no code, but this seemed interesting.

This worked for me (select the range you want to work on before running):

**EDIT2:** now handles adjoining edits without adding extra text

```
Sub FlipDeletesAndInserts()

    Dim rng As Range, rev As Revision, rngRev As Range
    Dim colDel As New Collection, colIns As New Collection
    Dim step As Long, txt As String

    If ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions Then
        Debug.Print "Tracked..."
    Else
        MsgBox "Track changes is not on!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Selection.Range 'operate on the selected text

    'Collect all of the revisions before changing anything,
    '  otherwise the new changes also will be processed!
    For Each rev In rng.Revisions
        If rev.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then colDel.Add rev
        If rev.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then colIns.Add rev
    Next rev

    For Each rev In colIns
        Set rngRev = rev.Range
        Debug.Print "Inserted:", rngRev.Text
        rev.Accept    'accept the new text
        rngRev.Delete '...then delete it
    Next rev

    For Each rev In colDel
        Set rngRev = rev.Range
        'EDIT: grab the text before accepting...
        txt = rngRev.Text
        Debug.Print "Deleted:", txt
        rev.Accept 'EDIT:added
        'insert the same deleted text as an insert
        '  immediately after the deletion
        rngRev.InsertAfter txt
    Next rev

End Sub
```

Before and after:

[image]

Comment: Tim, that is fantastic. Thank you so much for helping out. I'm afraid I'm very new to this, so didn't have any worthwhile code to share at first. Your solution gets me 80% of the way there, but there are some minor wrinkles I was hoping you could help with.

Comment: It all relates to the deletions. First, I need the red mark-up to disappear, so that only the reversed blue text is shown. I can get this by adding "rev.Accept", which is great, and gets the macro to work perfectly on a simple paragraph. However, where two revisions are next to each other, the text that is inserted in reversing the first (if its a deletion) seems to get added to the next rev in colRev. So, on the next iteration, the text added for the first revision either gets accepted or deleted in processing the second. Does that make sense? Any thoughts you have would be much appreciated!

Comment: See my edits - I think this is closer to what you're looking for.  It basically just "flips" the status of insert to delete, and *vice-versa*. You can reverse the changes by running it a second time.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Very grateful for your work. While it now works on a simple paragraph like your eg., I'm still having the second issue above - ie. Where two different Revisions aren't separated by unrevised text (usually deletion then insertion), the 'flipping' causes the flipped text be added to next Revision (rev) in colRev - Eg. "here's some {deleted text}[inserted text] to use", when flipped, becomes "here's some [deleted text][inserted text] to use", and the next rngRev.Text becomes "deleted textinserted text", so it then becomes "here's some {deleted textinserted text} to use". Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried all sorts of ways around this. I think it might involve creating a placeholder variable for the next Revision before each 'flip' and then resetting it at the end of each loop (after it becomes corrupted by the flip). I've tried this, but the placeholder (As Revision) changes as soon as the original does. I've tried capturing the Range.Text of the next revision as String and then replacing it at the end of the loop, but I don't know how to edit Range.Text of a Revision. Or would moving the actual Range of the next Revision (to start after the newly inserted text) work better? Thanks!

Comment: Tim Williams, you are my hero. Thank you so much! I made a few minor tweaks for functionality perferences (eg. turning Track Changes off again at the end if they were off to begin with, rather than using the pop-up, etc.), but you nailed it. I am eternally grateful, and resolved to learn more about all of this so that I can one day give back to the Stack Overflow community. Thank you.